# Ignore types of files when you tab from the command line

Tags: bash, vim, wildcards

One of the nice features of vim is that you can ask it to ignore certain types of files when you hit tab by using the following command in vimrc:

```
set wildignore+=*.hi,*.pyc,*.o
```

Is there a similar setting for `bash` so I can ignore types of files when I tab in the command line?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The bash variable you are looking for is `FIGNORE`, for your example

```
export FIGNORE=$FIGNORE:.hi:.pyc:.o
```

I personally still cannot live without

```
export FIGNORE=$FIGNORE:CVS
```

Comment: What is `CVS`? A filename or something with special meaning?

Comment: @FrozenFlame, `CVS` is the directory where the archaic version control system cvs (http://www.nongnu.org/cvs/) stores its control files. The example shows how `FIGNORE` may contain both file and directory patterns.